# Should I build a node module with ES6

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I am planning to build a node module and I want to use ES6, basically because it will give me the opportunity to learn it better but I am not sure whether it's the best tool to use.

I tried searching npmjs.org, but did not find any module that was built with ES6 best I saw was coffeescript.

I would like to know if you would advise I use ES6 and the little gotchas I should expect.

Thanks

Comment: "the best I saw was coffeescript" - I think you mean "worst"

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/8

Answer (score 1):

If you write it with ES2015 you likely want to compile it to ES5 using something like Babel before publishing to npm at this point. Conventions or solutions may emerge for publishing both versions in the same package and letting consumers select the desired one.

If you do decide to use Babel to compile, check out the [runtime transformer](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/).

Comment: Thanks JMM, I used Babel to compile to ES5 before publishing using NPM `prepublish` command and your hint on babel-runtime was gold. Never knew about it until you mentioned it.